# Deploy Laravel with LAMP (Ubuntu): Error The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, deployment, lamp

I try to do my first deploy Laravel 7 + LAMP (Ubuntu).

I succeeded to install Laravel repo I can see my homepage (http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/).

But when I try to navigate into the website I get this Error:
The requested URL was not found on this server.

I think that i've correctly installed LAMP and Laravel.

The DB is set, I've done the migration.

The problem is probably with the .htaccess, I set my in the repo folder (`domain.it/repo`):

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
    # if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled

    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /
    # NOT needed unless you're using mod_alias to redirect

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    # Direct all requests to /public folder
</IfModule>
```

And that's my apache2 conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ServerAdmin social.legambientecapannori@gmail.com
  ServerName legambientecapannoriepianalucchese.it
  ServerAlias www.legambientecapannoriepianalucchese.it

  DocumentRoot /var/www/legambientecapannoriepianalucchese.it/legambiente/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Ah, i've

Thanks in advance

---

Solved :)

I write the solution for those who will have the same problem

There was an error on the virtual host conf file:
<Directory **/var/www/html**>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

Comment: Can you share the `virtual host` you are using for your domain please ? You should have `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/legambiente/public`.

Comment: Update your question with it, do not share it as a comment as it cannot be formatted correctly and looks horrible, either way, it looks okay.

Comment: Ok you're right, i put all inside the question... do you have any idea? what can i do for detect the probem?

Comment: I am not sure if defining `Directory` with those options is a problem or not, because I do not have `Directory` defined with anything and it works okay. Is this happening for any URL or worst, the main domain ? Does any URL work or none ?

Comment: The Directory in the virtual host or in the apache2.conf?

Comment: the welcome page was ok until an hour ago... only that... now i got this error: ```You don't have permission to access this resource.```

Comment: `Virtual Host`, I have no idea about that new error, what other active sites (config) do you have there ?

Comment: I have only that site :(

Comment: I think I reset the VPS and restart from the beginning

Comment: Thank you very much Matias! I will let you know if i succeed

Comment: No problem, tag me again here.

Comment: The error still remain... now seem to me that laravel can't generate routes...

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your Apache configuration. Run `php artisan route:list` and see if the routes are generated accordingly. Also, did you modify the `.htaccess` in `public` folder ? It must work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks again Matias... ```php artisan route:list``` that's what i did... then I recheck all conf file and finally find the error...